# Remove '#' from a URL in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have written a script remove the `#` from URL & scroll to the particular div. Its working for the normal url like

```
10.0.1.22/dev/pg/blog/all/
```

But its not working for the URL like

```
10.0.1.22/dev/pg/search/?tag=a&entity_subtype=blog&entity_type=object&search_type=entities#39531
```

Its not removing the `#` from URL & also the scrolling also not working.

Script

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $(".full_view_btn").live('click', function(){
        var divid = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var long_desc = "#inner_descrip" + divid;   
        var short_desc = "#listing_desp" + divid;
        var shw_mre_btn = "#full_view" + divid;

        if($(long_desc).is( ':hidden' )){
            $('.long_desc').hide();
            $('.short_desc').show();
            $(long_desc).show();
            $(short_desc).hide();
            $('.full_view_btn').text('Show more');
            $(shw_mre_btn).text('Show less');
          } else{
              $(long_desc).hide();
              $(short_desc).show();
              $(shw_mre_btn).text('Show more');
          }

        if (location.pathname.replace('/^\//','') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
          var target = $(this.hash);
          target = target.length ? target : $('[id=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
          if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top-60
            }, 500);
                target.parent().find('#highlight_div'+divid).css("box-shadow", "0 0 2px 1px #cccccc");
            setTimeout(function() {
                target.parent().find('#highlight_div'+divid).css("box-shadow", "none");
            }, 1000);
            return false;
          }
        }

    });

});
```

Any idea guys how to fix this ?  I cant find where is the error ?

Comment: create jsfiddle please.

Comment: which browser are you using?

Comment: @ssut All browser same problem...

Comment: @PratikJoshi This is an small portion i have shown it here....the page is a list so unable to show in fiddle

Comment: @RIADev ,post code before if() Also ,so it will make some sense

Comment: @ssut see this.hash will check the url of the current page

Comment: @PratikJoshi edited plz check

Comment: take a look at [this link](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/parsing-urls-with-the-dom/) for parsing URL's

Comment: @PratikJoshi No nothing the script is working up to replacing the text show more

Comment: @RIADev ,please create jsfiddle

Comment: @serakfalcon whats that ?? I need to create a new function for that ??

Comment: that would parse the URL for you, so you can extract the hash and any other relevant info.

Comment: Okay guys i solved i just changed the div id now its working fine...thnx for your input..

Answer (score 1):

you cannot use jQuery object to wrap hash string otherwise you will get empty array because the input parameter for jQuery should be an selector. You need target as DOM element wrapped by jQuery object to use methods like offset.

So you have to change the target to or whatever should be the target to scroll down

```
var target = $(this.target);
```

Comment: yes the `taget.length` its saying `0` but how its working for small URL in my question ??

Comment: if the target value is set to 0 following condition isn't evaluated and is simple skipped

Comment: Yes i know that...& i tried your solution its not working either...yes in the console.log(target) is showing selector the `#35166` the id

Comment: it's hart to guess right behaviour, could you publish whole page

Comment: @Martin... i fixed it the script is 101% correct...i just changed my parent div then its working perfectly thnx for your tym..